# Honda CBR125R oil leak after service

Tags: motorcycle, oil-leak

I am not mechanically inclined at all, so I take my bike to an approved Honda dealership for services. 
Unfortunately, the other day my oil pump broke with a long trip still ahead. Unfortunately I could not stop driving because of the dangerous conditions I was in. 
Taking it for a service revealed (understandably) damage to the internals of the engine. 
At this point, parking it overnight at home, the bike leaked a tiny bit of oil.

The dealership repaired everything and sent me on my way. After a weeks driving I noticed the bike started leaking fuel, so I took it back...
They started it and looked around the bike, they said everything was fine and will assess it in detail when I brought it for its next service.

They topped the bike up with more oil (not that it was low) and told me to check the oil frequently.

So checking its oil for the first time today, leveling the bike, it spilt some oil...
Is it possible they put too much oil in?
There is no smoke emitted from the exhaust and the bike runs as smoothly as ever.

Should I be worried?

It is leaking from a breather pipe (from what I can tell)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your problem is to much oil than no, most engines designs are not sensitive to that, you can search and read other answers on this forum regarding too much oil.

the breather is exactly where extra engine oil would get ejected during normal operation.  other designs have a breather in the cylinder head as well which can possibly expel engine oil due to other problems.

since you mention no smoke out the exhaust, then oil isn't leaking excessively by through the cylinder past the piston rings to begin with so as far as excessive oil goes seems your ok

Comment: Thank you, so you reckon it should be safe to wait until the end of the month for its next service?

Comment: Again strictly speaking about too much oil and things appear to run fine, then certainly i believe its fine to not rush service for this.   Though now im curious why you seem to be servicing it so often.

Comment: I usually take it for a 6000KM (usually once every 2 months) oil change and general check up, is that too frequently?

Comment: i would follow whatever schedule your​ owner's manual suggested. but doing it more often won't hurt your bike, just maybe your wallet